# Why is node.js sending the entire public folder, When only root index.html specified?

Tags: node.js, express, server

So I am making a node.js server for my webpage. And after having added root route that sends the index.html it also sends the game.html page with out it being specified. The game.html file is in a folder called game in the root directory. So I am wondering why is it sending the game.html file? And is it supposed to happened, with out me saying what the server is supposed to send in the "/game" path?

I am using Node.js and Express.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));

// ROUTES
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html", {root: "public"});
})

// Listening
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at port http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

Comment: your `app.use(express.static("public"));` line of code will serve ALL files in that public folder that match an incoming request.  So, if `game.html` is in that folder and you send your server a request that matches that file, then `express.static()` will send it - that's what it is used for.  I can't tell from your question is that's what you're asking or not.

Comment: Yes, I am using that, express.static() to get the css for the index.htm, So is this the reason it sends the entire page? And if so how can I make it only send the css and js fils?

Comment: You need to ONLY put things in the `public` directory that you want `express.static()` to send.  If you don't want it to send `game.html`, then don't put that file in the `public` directory tree.

Comment: ok, but is it a problem that it is doing this then? For people on limited network. Like is this a bad way to make sure the css get sent with the html file then?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  `express.static()` does not send ANYTHING that was not requested by a client.  `express.static()` is often used for static files like CSS and JS files or even static HTML files - that's what it is built for.  It is efficient for that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help :). That answers my question, It was more like is it ok to use in a way question. Sorry if it was not worded well enough, English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have two route handlers that can send responses back to incoming requests.

This one:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html", {root: "public"});
});
```

is pretty obvious.  If the request is `/`, then send back the `index.html` file.

This one:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

tells express to compare the incoming path of the request to any files in your public directory and, if they match, then send that file back as the response to that request.  This is exactly  what `express.static()` is designed for and what it is supposed to do.  It is commonly used for serving static resources such as CSS files, JS files and even static HTML files since one route can automatically serve an entire directory hierarchy.

So, if an incoming request arrives for `/game/game.html` and, the public directory contains this:

```
public
  game
    game.html
```

Then, `express.static("public")` will find a match for `/game/game.html` and will send back the `game.html` file as the response.  This is working as designed.

Because of this, you should never put anything that you don't want automatically served inside the directory that you pass to `express.static()` - in your specific code example, the "public" directory.